# How to enable/disable USB access in android

Tags: android, usb

I am using android 2.2 which is not having any API's to access the USB functionality. Then how can control the disable/enable functionality of USB. Is it possible to use with jni? Is there any jni lib available?

Thanks in advance
Ram

Comment: What do you mean by 'USB functionality'? The USB Mass Storage, USB debugging or the new USB host and accessory modes?

Comment: yes all the above features..in 3.0 adk of android is having the direct suport for USB, but its not availble in 2.2.. thats y i asking is there any way to use it for 2.2 version

Answer (score 0):

Those features are not accessible to any ADK below 3.1, though USB accessory was backported to 2.3.4.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html